# Raster to ASCII export in R- ASCII full of NA's

Tags: r, null, export, ascii, raster

I am trying to export a raster file (.tif) as an ascii in R for subsequent analysis. The goal is to replicate [this](http://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO201807356123511.pub) methodology (area-to-point-regression kriging), but the produced file is full of NA's. My original raster has "normal" values.
Here is a [link](https://easyupload.io/m/av6no1) to my ascii and tif files.
The code I have used so far:

```
library(raster)

#import raster
ntl = raster("mydir/ntl.tif")

#export as ascii format
writeRaster(ntl, "mydir/ntl.asc", format="ascii", overwrite = T)
```

I am using Windows 10, RStudio Version 1.4.1717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raster mostly consists of `NA`s, as can be illustrated like this (I prefer to use `terra` the replacement of `raster`):

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("ntl.tif")
plot(x, colNA="light blue")
```

[image]

Most of the image is light blue, that is, covered with cells that are `NA`

You can remove most `NA`s with `trim`

```
y <- trim(x)
plot(y, colNA="light blue")
```

[image]

You are not saying why you are creating an ascii file. I assume that you want to read the values with some other tool that does not know about spatial data file formats. In that case you might consider `as.data.frame` with `na.rm=TRUE` instead.

```
d <- as.data.frame(x, na.rm=TRUE, cells=TRUE)
head(d)
#       cell      ntl
#44592 44592 3.615484
#44593 44593 6.819953
#45010 45010 2.256919
#45011 45011 3.350195
#45012 45012 9.617457
#45013 45013 8.812189
```

And then save it to file, for example with

```
write.csv(d, "test.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I masked the raster using a polygon in QGIS before I use it in R, so naturally I assumed that the NA's weren't exist. Anyway, I edit my question and I included the reason why I need ascii format.